# Geometry of arithmetical property

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is there geometric proof of this exact problem:

How to prove geometrically that $\frac{|CD|}{|BC|} + \frac{|DE|}{|BC|} = \frac{|EC|}{|BC|}?$ Angle $BCE$ is right angle.

[image]

I don't want arithmetical proof (using $\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c} = \frac{a + b}{c}$), but geometrical, using for example simillar triangles.

Comment: The angle in C is 90 degrees?

Comment: Perhaps give more context to your question. I don't understand what exactly would be "allowed"

Comment: So, you can use geometrical tools to prove this. For example for any $a \in \mathbb{R_\geq0}$ one can construct $\sqrt{a}$ and this can be proven using simillar triangles. And so operations with square (and any other rational) exponent can be proven using geometry (Descartes algebratization of geometry). I think that in simillar fashion can be proven property $\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c} = \frac{a + b}{c}$ from picture above. If we look on $x = \frac{a}{c}$ like "amount (%) of $c$ required to make $a$" then this property is logically obvious. But is this geometrically valid?

Comment: Since BC is common you just need to show that  CD+DE = EC, and this is geometrical:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much simpler version has been offered in the comment. Here is another artificial one.  Since 1 has been used for labelling uploaded diagram, I let o to mean 1.

Label the regions of areas as shown.

[image]

$[\triangle BCD] + [\triangle B’DE]$

= ([0]) + ([4] + [3])

= ([0]) + ([2] + [3])

= ([0] + [2} + [3])

= $[\triangle BCE]$

Then, $0.5BC \times CD + 0.5BC \times DE = 0.5BC \times CE$

Result follows after dividing throughout by $0.5(BC)^2$.

Comment: $BCD$ is area? I am asking for sum of ratios of sides...

Comment: @1b3b Yes. Edited to clear things up.

Comment: Maybe cleaner way is with percentages, but this works also because of proven properties of area arithmetic. Thanks